# Заполнение и поиск в двумерном массиве

Tags: c++

Всем привет, работаю с двумерным массивом таким образом заполняю:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            r[i][j] = i*j;
    }
```

Потом мне надо найти элементы в этом массиве. Опять придется прогонять через двойной цикл, что думаю не очень хорошо. Как думаете, что тут будет лучше использовать?(что-нибудь из stl библиотеки может). Нужно чтобы по времени выполнения было быстрее.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, массив у вас симметричный (уже меньше искать - второй массив нужно делать `for(int j=i;`), а во-вторых, что именно вы искать намерены? в таком массиве можно и по-другому попробовать искать, кроме как последовательным поиском...

Comment: он не симметричный, это для примеры написал. В некоторых строчках будет 10 значений заполнено, в других 20. Буду искать значения записанные, нужно будет индекс узнать.

Comment: "Опять придется прогонять через двойной цикл" - разумеется.

Comment: Если использовать библиотеку stl, можно через find искать

Comment: Тогда, раз никакой дополнительной информации - то последовательный поиск. Но! можно скопировать и отдельно отсортировать структуры - значение с индексами - по значению, и тогда поиск будет O(log N). Если искать нужно много и часто...

Comment: А с stl библиотекой будет быстрее работать? Я думаю может вектор пар сделать

Comment: Даже с использованием STL сложность алгоритма в общем случае не будет меньше `O(N*M)`.

Comment: Пару вопросов - массив типа int? ищете любое вхождение или все (или совпадений гарантированно нет)? Нужно вернуть оба индекса, так? Какие размеры массива? Если я правильно понял - это может быть еще и не полностью заполненный массив?просто это все влияет на выбор метода...

Comment: типа int. Будет точно 1 вхождение.Вернуть надо один индекс(второй)размеры всегда варьируется. Разная длина строк в массиве будет

Answer (score 1):

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    template <class T>
    // нет никакого цикла 
    const std::pair<size_t, size_t> findVal(T* p, const size_t r, const size_t n, T item)
{
    size_t first = 0, second = 0;
    T* I = std::find(p, p + r * n, item);
    first = (I - p) / n;
    second = (I - p) % n;
    return std::make_pair(first, second);
}
// тест
int main()
{        
    const size_t row = 8, column = 10;
    int r[row][column];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            r[i][j] = i*j;
            std::cout <<std::setw(4) << r[i][j] <<' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    const int k = 56;
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> coord = findVal(r[0], row, column, k);
    if (coord.first != row)
        std::cout << "r[" << coord.first <<"][" << coord.second <<"] == " << k;
    else
        std::cerr << " error:  there is no object with such a value";
    return 0;
}
но лучше такой код прятать в шаблонный  класс 
template <class T>
class Some_type {....};
Some_type matrix(r[0]);
matrix.find(val);....
```